# jQuery hotkeys...not so global

Tags: jquery, events, dom, hotkeys, codemirror

Basically, I'm using [jQuery Hotkeys plugin](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) by Mr Resig to capture and handle shortcuts like `ctrl+o` etc...

OK, maybe I don't uderstand the concept, but I was under the impression that a `ctrl+o` triggered *anywhere* inside the document will be captured by a document hotkey handler.

For example, the following code works in general...

```
jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+o', fn);
```

However, it fails miserably if the user triggers the hotkey when inside an input box.

It only works if I do the following:

```
jQuery('body, input').bind('keydown', 'ctrl+o', fn);
```

Which is pretty bad for my health since it involves binding the damn handler each time a new input box is added to the DOM. Worse still, I have no idea what to bind to in the case of complex widgets like CodeMirror.

Dunno if my problem makes sense, perhaps I'm using the wrong approach? I also tried binding to the following objects, but it didn't work: `window`, `document`, `body`, `div[contains the whole page]`

**NB:** You can [try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/XKWjM/).

Comment: maybe you can use the `on()` here? so it'll work with every input ever added. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Topener I don't want to *just* bind to all *current* inputs, but any *future* ones as well. The beauty of adding events this way is that you don't need global variables to contain your event handling functions, you just do it once when needed.

Comment: But the point here isn't about me adding the events, but rather the hotkey functionality should be doing it itself. I mean, that's the point of a hotkey....pressing `ctrl+s` in Netbeans editor produces the same effect of doing it inside netbeans project listing (as an example).

Comment: Something like jQuery('body').bind(...) and jQuery('body').children().bind(...) ?

Comment: @Edward Perhaps it's too difficult to grasp, but here goes: `.children()` or any other jQuery selector works over **existing elements**, not any that might be added in the future. I need global hotkeys, not binding events everywhere each time the DOM is changed.

Comment: @Christian `on()` binds to future dom elements too.

Comment: @Topener Nope: http://jsfiddle.net/wycAd/

Comment: @Christian it does actually: http://jsfiddle.net/wycAd/1/

Comment: @Topener My bad, seems you are right. So much for screwing up with parameters. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually intended functionality of the plugin:

```
// Don't fire in text-accepting inputs that we didn't directly bind to
if ( this !== event.target && (/textarea|select/i.test( event.target.nodeName ) ||
    event.target.type === "text") ) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Well, to be honest, I don't know how to fix my issue without changing that code :(

Comment: I suppose I could pass on an option to disable the feature...then submit a patch to Resig's...

Comment: Yeah, I don't see a way around it without modifying the plugin in some way.

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing it out. Don't know why it didn't pass through my mind to check the plugin code in the first place...

Comment: **I am pleased to announce that this also solved my issues with CodeMirror.**

Comment: @Christian I know this is an old, old, **old** post, but how did it *solve* the issue for you? Did you fork the script, modify this and use your own version? I could ask a follow up question but it would probably be closed as a dupe! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, JqueryHotkeys failed miserably if the user triggers the hotkey when inside an input box.

Alternatively, when I browsed I found out [shortcut.js](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/shortcut.js), which provides similar functionality as that of Jquery-Hotkeys.

**Importantly** it also has an option to enable or disable the "user defined shortcut function" when inside an input box.